# Get a StreamSubscription from an on-* attribute in dart

Tags: events, dart

In my custom element i have some elements, which have an 'on-input' attribute. They all call the same function. So on every change in a input element the function gets called. But i'd like to get the StreamSubscription from the first Event, pause it and start it again if the function is done.

So is there a way to get a StreamSubscription from the 'on-*' attribute?

Setting an onInput event from the Dart Code is not an Option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the event listener imperatively it's just what you get.

```dart
$['my-input'].onXxx.listen...
```

or

```dart
$['my-input'].on['Xxx'].listen...
```

Just read your last sentence. Why is it not an option?

You can create your own StreamController and add the events in the declarively assigned event handlers.

```dart
  StreamController<Event> _inputController = new StreamController<Event>();
  Stream<Event> get onInput => _inputController.stream;

  void inputHandler(Event e) {
    _inputController.add(e);
  }
```

You can make `onInput` a broadcast stream if you need

```dart
Stream<Event> _inputStream = _exitController.stream.asBroadcastStream();

...

// subscribe to the event
onInput.listen...
```

But this way you get basically the same as you get by directly using the event streams of the element as shown above.

Comment: Like I said in the question, setting the event listener imperatively is not on Option for me, is this case..

Comment: Sorry, I missed your last sentence at first. I already updated my answer. It would help if you could explain what's the point of this requirement.

Comment: Since my element contains various input element / custom input elements which will be shown depending of the type of my custom element. (Using templates). These elements have different event. Some have on-input, some dont. So its much easier to set the events on each element as attribute, instead of using a great amount of ifs to look which element i got in this case and set the event via dart code.

Comment: You could add your custom attribute and do the linking in code. `querySelectorAll(`[custom-event]').forEach((e) = e.on[e.attributes['event-name']].listen...` Where the attribute `custom-event` is just for selecting the elements and `event-name="input"` could be a second attribute which indicates what event to listen on.

Comment: That's would also be a good way to solve that. I'm looking at the moment if the StreamController would help me, and if not I'll probably gonna do this the way you described it.

Comment: But anyways, there is no option like element.getEventStreams or something like that? Since on-* is an EventStream, there should also be a StreamSubscription accessible somewhere.

Comment: Declarative `on-xxx="{{xxxHandler}}"` is similar to what I explained in my comment above just that Polymer does it for you. I don't think there is a way to get access to the subscription Polymer uses internally.

Comment: Too bad this doesnt work. Anyways you helped me with your answer and answer the the question.